# help! I get the wrong screen size after install the nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, screen

My screen always flash when i right-click the gnome-terminal, so i wonder whether i haven't install the right drive. so i run the fallowing command:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

after that, i reboot the system, but I got the wrong screen size,only 640*480

what can i do to rescure my system?

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia is like a pain every time. There is lot of reason that I found wrong size of monitor screen.

I preferred download right driver from nvidia site. There is lot of manual u can found about how to install and remove nvidia drivers on Ubuntu.

1. Know what hardware u use in your machine with lspci command.
2. Once get information about hardware, then download driver from nvidia site.
3. Download done, go to cli mode with alt+clt+f2, turn off your graphic manager in Ubuntu with... Service lightdm stop
4. Install that run script and remove all previous settings of nvidia in /etc/X11/sort.conf file.
5. Restart lightdm and see your proble get fix or not.

Hope you will found something good.

Comment: sorry,I fallowed you suggestion, but it still doesn't work well